# How do I get the CSS property top from a element in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How do I get the CSS property top from a element in javascript.

I have tried `document.getElementById(element).offsetTop` however this always returns 0. When I have set top: 500px; in the CSS of element.

Comment: google for currentStyle.top and getComputedStyle().

Answer (score 4):

`offsetTop` gets the position of the element on the page (relative to an offsetParent, which is any positioned element or occasionally some other types of element) in pixels as a Number.

`style.top` gets the String value of the `top` property in `style="top: 500px"` **inline attributes only**.

If you want to get a `top` style value that has been set from a stylesheet, you can't use `style.top` which will just return `''` to tell you `top` hasn't been set in the `style` attribute. Instead there is `window.getComputedStyle` which is defined by DOM Level 2 Style, and `element.currentStyle` which is used by IE. (Older browsers won't support either.)

```
var top= (window.getComputedStyle?
    window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('top') :
    element.currentStyle? element.currentStyle.top : '0'
);
```

There are usually better ways around that don't involve trying to read stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

`offsetTop` returns the top offset to the node lower in the tree that has `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;` set.

Do you have the parent's position set to **relative** or **absolute**?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
element.style.top
```